# Pass a parameter into a function setting a setTimeout?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way I can call this from another module specifying the timeout in brackets?

```
var addActiveDiv = () => {
  var activeEl = document.querySelector(".o-wrapper");
  setTimeout(() => {
    activeEl.classList.add("is-active");
  }, 1850);
}

addActiveDiv();

export { addActiveDiv }
```

Something like

`addActiveDiv(2000);` *where 2000 is the **new** timeout?*

Comment: Yes, give it a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify the function as taking a parameter, and pass that parameter to `setTimeout`?

```
var addActiveDiv = (ms) => {
  var activeEl = document.querySelector(".o-wrapper");
  setTimeout(() => {
    activeEl.classList.add("is-active");
  }, ms);
}

addActiveDiv(2000);

export { addActiveDiv }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parameters or default parameters.

```
var addActiveDiv = (timeout = 1850) => {
  var activeEl = document.querySelector(".o-wrapper");
  setTimeout(() => {
    activeEl.classList.add("is-active");
  }, timeout);
}

addActiveDiv();

export { addActiveDiv }
```

```
import { addActiveDiv } from "foobar";

addActiveDiv(2000);
```